# My code is not working, "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is not working and I have no clue why:

```
neword = '100115'
val=0
neword2=''
for n in range(0,len(neword),3):
  neword2 = chr(int(neword)[val]+int(neword)[val+1]+int(neword)[val+2])
  val+=3
print(neword2)
```

it was supposed to print: ds

Answer (score 1):

You have to index the string first, *then* pass the result to `int`.

```
int(neword)[val]  # WRONG
int(neword[val])  # RIGHT
```